# Make YARN clean up appcache before retry

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

The situation is the following:

1. A YARN application is started. It gets scheduled.
2. It writes a lot to its appcache directory.
3. The application fails.
4. YARN restarts it. It goes pending, because there is not enough disk space anywhere to schedule it. The disks are filled up by the appcache from the failed run.

If I manually intervene and kill the application, the disk space is cleaned up. Now I can manually restart the application and it's fine.

I wish I could tell the automated retry to clean up the disk. Alternatively I suppose it could count that used disk as part of the new allocation, since it belongs to the application anyway.

I'll happily take any solution you can offer. I don't know much about YARN. It's an Apache Spark application started with `spark-submit` in `yarn-client` mode. The files that fill up the disk are the shuffle spill files.

Answer (score 4):

So here's what happens:

1. When you submit yarn application [it creates a private local resource](https://hortonworks.com/blog/resource-localization-in-yarn-deep-dive/) folder (appcache directory).
2. Inside this directory spark block manager [creates](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/DiskBlockManager.scala#L132) directory for storing block data. As mentioned:

> local directories and won't be deleted on JVM exit when using the external shuffle service.

3. This directory can be cleaned via:

   - [Shutdown hook](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/DiskBlockManager.scala#L169). This what's happen when you kill the application.
   - Yarn DeletionService. It should be done automatically on application finish. Make sure `yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec`=0. Otherwise there is some [unresolved yarn bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42152231/3271168)

Comment: Thanks! It's been 1.5 years since I posted the question, and I haven't actually seen the problem manifest since then. So I cannot easily confirm your answer, but it makes sense. My only reservation is that you say the DeletionService cleans up when the application finishes. What if it does not finish, just fails and gets retried? Same thing?